# Node Modules : unstall package

Tags: npm

How to unintall npm package from Angular 4 application in visual studio code ?

See attached screen. I have @progress, @telerik npm modules which are not in use anymore.

I tried with following commands but no luck

```
npm uninstall --save @progress
npm uninstall --save @telerik

npm uninstall @progress
npm uninstall @telerik
```

Even If remove them from package.json it is installed automatically when I build or fire npm install command.

See attached screenshot.

[image]

Comment: make it is getting downloaded from another package as dependency

Comment: if it is dev dependency, use -dev npm uninstall --save-dev @progress

Comment: as --save will not help in removing package , if it is in dev dependency

Comment: I got the solution.Manually I removed them from package.json and run npm install command and it's removed. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: cool.. glad it got resolved